# Manually implementing one piece of validation using a ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

ASP.NET MVC 5 question here.  I have a ViewModel for a form which allows someone to create a new message consisting of a body, subject, and recipient username:

```
public class CreateMessageViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Subject is required!")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Body is required!")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Recipient Username")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Recipient is required!")]
    public string RecipientUsername { get; set; }
}
```

For the RecipientUsername, I need to also validate that the specified username actually exists, otherwise reject the input and show the message "Invalid user!".  I'm not sure where to put this code to make it happen.  To clarify, I already have a simple one-liner function to check if a user exists or not.  I just can't seem to figure out where to put that one-line call.

I did figure out a way to sorta kinda handle this, which I guess works, and that is in the Controller, manually check for the user's existence before the "if (ModelState.IsValid)" check.  That will prevent catastrophe in that the message won't be attempted to be saved with an invalid username, but it doesn't nicely print out the error message in the same way that the Required attribute causes it to.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one-off check, then what you're doing is the best bang for the buck.

But if it is more common in your project, and can be potentially shared (by controllers/viewmodel way) then an option is to implement a custom validation attribute.

```
public class UserNameExists : ValidationAttribute
{
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
 {
  // do your look-up check and return ValidationResult.Success accordingly.
 }
}
```

now you can use the above attribute like any other inbuilt one, with friendly messages etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could handle this.

One is to use the `RemoteAttribute` on the property. The main benefit is that validation can occur on the client before submitting the form. For an example refer:

[How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx)

The other is to add a model state error in the post method

```
public ActionResult Save(CreateMessageViewModel model)
{
  bool exists = // check the existence of RecipientUsername
  if (!exists)
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("RecipientUsername ", "The user does not exist");
  }
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }
  // all good
}
```

This will display the message *"The user does not exist"* wherever you have defined `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RecipientUsername)`. Alternatively, the first parameter can be `string.Empty` to display it where you have defined `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`